# Ajax dont answer to other code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Why cant i work with ajax output in other code?

```
var str1 = "";
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/main.php',
    success: function(data){
        data = minify_html(data);
        str1 = data;
        alert(str1); // return minified html code
    }
   });
alert(str1); // return nothing
```

Comment: You probably want to do a GET request: `type: 'GET'`, since you're not posting anything to `main.php`

Comment: I don't understand what it is that you're asking

Comment: POST/GET is irrelevant.  @j08691 they're asking how to get `str1` - but it's nothing because that code runs before the ajax call has completed.  There's a clue in the name 'asynchronous'...  see duplicate.   (this gets asked about 3-4 times an hour...)

Comment: So it's popular problem and i was trying to solve the problem for 2-3 hours myself but i couldnt and asked the question.